# Boolean and resolver API method URL conventions

Tags: api, rest, naming-conventions, restful-url

We are using below URL conventions for the rest API development but need suggestions on how to form guidelines for Boolean and resolver methods.

The below are the url's we are using for the Employee entity:

1. Create Employee -  POST  /employees
2. Update Employee - PUT  /employees/{id}
3. Delete Employee - Delete /employees/{id}
   4.Read Employee    - GET    /employees/{id}
4. Find XXX         -GET  /employees (Query Params)
5. ResolveXXX       - what should be the URL?
6. isValidEmployee   -what should be the URL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> 5. ResolveXXX

This sounds like you're changing the state of that XXX resource, so i'd go for a PUT

> 6. isValidEmployee

You could simply have an IsValid boolean property on the Employee model, and let the client GET that model and then check the property

Comment: Resolver is not changing the state. It is more like finder methods. Instead of returning null it throws an error if an entity is not found. For boolean methods i might have method like isValidEmplyeeByDeptId,IsvalidEmployeeForSlary like wise isValidEmployeeXXX. So i might have 'n' number of boolean methods.

Comment: Resolver is not changing the state. It is more like finder methods. Instead of returning null it throws an error if an entity is not found. For boolean methods i might have method like isValidEmplyeeByDeptId,IsvalidEmployeeForSlary like wise isValidEmployeeXXX. So i might have 'n' number of boolean methods. The crux here is that the  client knows the employeeId and he wants to fire series of boolean methods.

Comment: you're thinking in a very SOAP way, you'll need to change this if you want to achieve [REST](http://martinfowler.com/articles/richardsonMaturityModel.html), in terms of resources, verbs & http status codes, instead of methods; therefore, resolver sounds like a GET which returns 404 not found instead of throwing an error, while for the validation you could simply return another property (besides the IsValid one), like an array containing the _invalid_ properties